# how to get common data from tables having primary key and foreign key

Tags: sql

I have two tables

1:pr_insertion77

```
create table pr_insertion77(pr_title varchar2(20) primarykey,pr_smalltitle varchar2(20),pr_desc varchar2(100),pr_category varchar2(20),
pr_startdate date,pr_enddate date,pr_bidtype number(2),pr_image long raw);
```

2:sellerdetails

```
create table sellerdetails( sellername varchar2(20),biddedproduct varchar2(20),price number(10),CONSTRAINT fk_pr_insertion77
    FOREIGN KEY (biddedproduct)
    REFERENCES pr_insertion77(pr_title)
```

I want to get sellername and price where `pr_insertion77.pr_title=sellerdetails.biddedproduct.`

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like java-ee, neither to hibernate or similar. It looks like plain SQL.
Therefore it would be nice to specify wich DBMS is targetted.

Your request is only related to the sellerdetails (price and sellername), and the condition you specified is always true since it is a foreign key except for null FK values (unless you want to filter on particular pr_insertion77, but this is not what you asked).

Query:

```
SELECT sellername, price FROM sellerdetails WHERE biddedproduct IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I want to filter on particular pr_insertion77 title...i want to get rows from sellerdetails where only biddedproduct is equal to pr_title

Comment: I want to filter on particular pr_insertion77 title...i want to get rows from sellerdetails where only biddedproduct is equal to pr_title

Comment: Then it's something like:SELECT sellername, price FROM sellerdetails WHERE biddedproduct='your_pr_title';

Comment: but i have to dynamically check all the pr_titles with the bidded product and then take out sellername and price from sellerdetails table

Comment: The value of pr_title is equal to the value of bidded_product since this is respectively  a primary key for pr_insertion77 and a foreign key for sellerdetails. You can take all of the pr_titles one by one and then look-up for the seller details, that would provide the eaxct same list of sellername/price as the first request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOIN.In case if for any detail in pr_insertion77 there is a corresponding detail in sellerdetails then use INNER JOIN

```
        SELECT sellerdetails.sellername,sellerdetails.price 
    FROM pr_insertion77 INNER JOIN sellerdetails 
ON pr_insertion77.pr_title=sellerdetails.biddedproduct;
```